# Convert large JSON file format

Tags: text-processing, json

I'd like to know if it's possible to convert the following format

```
{"timestamp":"1579053433","name":"1.10.207.64","value":"node-fnk.pool-1-10.dynamic.totinternet.net","type":"ptr"}
{"timestamp":"1579067130","name":"1.10.207.65","value":"node-fnl.pool-1-10.dynamic.totinternet.net","type":"ptr"}
{"timestamp":"1579098581","name":"1.10.207.66","value":"node-fnm.pool-1-10.dynamic.totinternet.net","type":"ptr"}
```

and end up with

```
1.10.207.64-1.10.207.64::node-fnk.pool-1-10.dynamic.totinternet.net;
1.10.207.65-1.10.207.65::node-fnl.pool-1-10.dynamic.totinternet.net;
1.10.207.66-1.10.207.66::node-fnm.pool-1-10.dynamic.totinternet.net;
```

The JSON file is 127 GB & 1,267,984,961 lines. The only thing that will change in each line is the IP & Hostname.

Comment: What have you tried, and how specifically was file size an issue?

Comment: Yes. Use a json parser. (I can't remember the name of any, at this time. However I know there is at least one in the Debian repos, and in python library, and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `jq` - for example, using the `\(...)` string interpolation

```
jq -r '"\(.name)-\(.name)::\(.value);"' file.json
```

As far as I know, it doesn't attempt to slurp the whole file unless you explicitly tell it to (using the `-s` / `--slurp` option), so while it may be *slow*, it shouldn't choke however large the file.

Comment: Getting the following error  c:\jq>jq -r '"\(.name)-\(.name)::\(.value);"' file.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'\(.name)-\(.name)::\(.value);'
jq: 1 compile error   I'm running jq in the same folder as the json file i want to convert.

Comment: @jim456 if your question is about `jq` on Windows, perhaps you should ask elsewhere? This is a Unix and Linux site.

Comment: I've got ubuntu running on a virtual machine now. How do i output the file with the new format once its finished.

Comment: @jim456 `jq` will write to the terminal by default - if you want to capture the output in a new file, you will need to re-direct it like `jq -r '...' > newfile`

Comment: i'm running in terminal `jq -r '"\(.name)-\(.name)::\(.value);"' -r '/home/james/Desktop/json/xch.json' > '/home/james/Desktop/output.txt'` would this be the correct way to output.

Comment: AFAIK you don't need the second `-r`

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to by `ctrl-alt-delor` in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570445/convert-large-json-file-format#comment1061063_570445), `python` is an option

For example, with a relatively recent `python3` version

```py
import sys, json

for line in sys.stdin:
    doc = json.loads(line)
    print(f'{doc["name"]}-{doc["name"]}::{doc["value"]}')
```

You would put this in a file (say `parse_json.py`) and run as follows:

```
python3 parse_json.py <json.file
```